# WP get page admin custom column from table in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, admin

I already created admin column in WP using this code:

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'page_custom_cols', 10);

function page_custom_cols($pages_columns, $post_type) {
$pages_columns['user_group'] = 'User Group';
return $pages_columns;
}
```

Now I added the function to get the user group id, this field is already in `wp_post` table but in a comma separated text just like this: " 1,7,2 " and I was able to display it using this function:

```
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'display_page_custom_cols', 10, 2);
function display_page_custom_cols($col_name, $post_id) {
  if ('user_group' == $col_name) {
     $pages = get_post($post_id);
      echo $pages->group_access;
  }
}
```

[And it was showing now](http://screencast.com/t/z1uJ3KinklN). My problem right now is I want to display the User Group Name not the `ID`. [It was in the table](http://screencast.com/t/StBmVBfD0) `custom_user_group`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$groups=$pages->group_access;
    $groupsArray = explode(',', $groups);
    foreach($groupsArray as $singleGroupId){
    //use some code to retrieve the group name from 'custom_user_group' with the help for $singleGroupId
    }
```

Use the above code and add your approach to retrieve the name using **$singleGroupId**